# How to correlate the request and response for the purpose of logging

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I'm using the Global filters to log the request/response which works fine, but now I'd like to   embed a correlation ID (Guid) in both to that I may tie the 2 together. What's preferred way to do this?

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: What do you mean by tie the two together? The filters have access to both the IHttpRequest request and corresponding IHttpResponse response.

Comment: I want to create a single GUID and use that to correlate a single request and response, then store each message in the db. Later I can query the db and look for the matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you are taking about these but you could do this with [ServiceStack Request and Response filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) Sounds like you want to do something like this...

1. **Create the Guid in the Request Attribute Filter** and save to db.
2. While still in the request filter store that Guid in into the IHttpRequest.Items dictionary. This dictionary is for you to use for anything you want. It will be avilable to all the ServiceStack services.
3. **Access that Guid in the Response Attribute filter** via the IHttpRequest variable and save response entry to database.